# javascript draggable music player not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am adding a draggable music player to my website. while it is showing up on the webpage, i am not able to drag it. please advise if there's any errors in this code. i got the code from somewhere else and they've written that make sure to import the fontawesome stylesheet in head, which i have done, but it's still not working.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<style type="text/css">
#musicplayer {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:18px auto;
align-items:center
width: 90px;
height: 24px;

font-size:11px;
font-family: kosugi;
color:#955136;

line-height:200%;

background:white;

border: 2px solid #F9CDE2;
border-radius: 2px;

}

#musictitle{
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #FFB0C9);
display:inline-block;
width: calc(109% - 10px - 0px);
margin-left: calc(4px + 0px);
}

#musicpixel{
width:120%;
padding-top:0px;
position:relative;

min-height: 20px;

background:white;

border-right: 2px solid #F9CDE2;
}

.overlay {
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
transition:0.3s ease;

background:white;
}

#musicplayer:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
transition:0.3s ease;
}

.playpause{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.playpause:hover{
cursor:help;
}

#musicpixel img{
display:block;
}

.marquee{
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 100%;
animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee{
0% {
transform: translate(0, 0);
}
100% {
transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
}
</style>

<body>

<!--make sure to import fontawesome cdn <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous"> in the head-->

<div id='musicplayer'>
<div id='musicpixel'>
<img src='https://graphic.neocities.org/tumblr_inline_oeqayhhdhP1uqb749_500.gif'>
<div class='overlay'>
<div class='playpause'><i class="fas fa-play"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id='musictitle'>
<span class='marquee'>this music player is draggable on desktop :)</span>
</div>
</div>

<audio id='musicsrc' loop src='https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6sfaqetvhk87pic/Just%20A%20Feeling.mp3'></audio>
</body>

<script>
document.querySelector('.playpause').addEventListener('click', playpause);

function playpause(){
if(document.querySelector('.playpause').innerHTML == '<i class="fas fa-play"></i>'){
document.querySelector('#musicsrc').play();
document.querySelector('.playpause').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>';
} else{
document.querySelector('#musicsrc').pause();
document.querySelector('.playpause').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-play"></i>';
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to drag?

Comment: the music player